# How do I include a JS variable in an EJS file in a GET request?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to write an ejs file with a for-each loop that displays, as text, names of javascript variables line by line. I want each name to be hyperlinked to a route, such as /getinfo, that renders a page that displays more information about the variable that was clicked on.

I tried to use an "a href" tag as follows:

```
<a href="/getinfo?name=" <%= variable.name>> <%= variable.name %></a>
```

I expected variable.name to be included in the URL's query parameters, but it won't be appended properly. Considering how HTML does not support string concatenation, I am not sure how to properly include this data in an HTTP GET request.

What would be a correct way to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Using template literal

```
<a href="<%= `/getinfo?name=${variable.name}${variable.name}` %>">
```

Regular `ejs` to output escaped html

```
<a href="/getinfo?name=<%= variable.name %><%= variable.name %>">
```